# How to use whoosh to get the term frequences in all collections?

Tags: python, nlp, whoosh

```
def scorer(self, searcher, fieldname, text, qf=1):
    """Returns an instance of :class:`whoosh.scoring.Scorer` configured
    for the given searcher, fieldname, and term text.
    """

    raise NotImplementedError(self.__class__.__name__)
```

i do not know the arguments in scorer function.Where are they coming from?and
the same to the function under this sentence.If i want to get the term frequences in all collections,not the weight in current doc.How can i do?

```
def _score(self, weight, length):
    # Override this method with the actual scoring function
    raise NotImplementedError(self.__class__.__name__)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you need to do is use `whoosh.reading.TermInfo`.
global term information can be found here.
It's updated when new document indexing.

As you said, want to get the term frequencies in all collections,
`TermInfo().weight()` I guess will do it.
some sample code like this:

```
from whoosh.fields import Schema, TEXT
from whoosh.analysis import StemmingAnalyzer
from whoosh.filedb.filestore import FileStorage
from whoosh import scoring

schema = Schema(body=Text(analyzer=StemAnalyzer(), stored=True))

storage = FileStorage("index")
ix = storage.open_index()

def user_weighting_func(searcher, filename, text, matcher):
    return float(searcher.term_info('body', text))

with ix.searcher(weighting=scoring.FunctionWeighting(user_weighting_func)) as searcher:
    qp = QueryParser("body", schema=schema)
    q = qp.parse("hello")
    result = searcher.search(q)
    for hit in results:
        print(hit.score, hit['body'])
```

In this code, the `hit.score` will be global term frequency.